# Handling Empty and Unknown Error Responses when Fetching Products from iTunes Store

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I am executing the following code to fetch available products from the iTunes store upon user opening the app:

```
getProducts() {
    const productIds = ["svs_halftyer", "svs_monthly"]; // These are dummy ids
    this.iap
      .getProducts(productIds)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (this.getProductsRetryCount < 20) {
          this.getProductsRetryCount += 1;
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.getProducts();
          }, 500);
        } else {
          this.saveGetProductsError(error);
        }
      });
  }
```

However, some of my users (approximately 50) encounter an error that results in an empty object
`{}` in the catch block of the function. These exceptions are logged to my backend, where I've counted the occurrences. Despite retrying the function up to 20 times in the case of an error, the issue persists.

Another error received by users is as follows:

```
{"errorMessage": "An unknown error occurred", "errorCode": 0}
```

This particular error has been reported around 50 times.

After consulting Apple's documentation [Apple Documentation on SKError.Code.unknown](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerror/code/unknown)
which mentions that the SKError.Code.unknown error may sometimes be resolved by retrying the request, I implemented a retry mechanism:

However, I have not been unable to identify the cause of these issues. I considered whether it might be due to In-App Purchases being disabled by the user, as detailed here: [Use Screen Time to turn off in-app purchases](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102470)

Has anyone encountered similar errors or have insights on what might be causing these issues and how to effectively handle them?

Comment: Why are you returning an empty object in the then? you aren't doing anything with the response. this is what cause users to not see anything.

Comment: @StackoverBlows it's not returning an empty function iam just consoling returned products array there. updated code